# Do you have to have a certain amount of reputation points to propose a new site on Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, area-51

To propose/add a new site, is there a certain number of reputation points needed on Stack Exchange before a site can be considered?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) is the site you need to go to in order to propose a new Stack Exchange site.

You need 50 rep on Area51 to propose a new site. This is easily earned **on Area51** because confirming your email address gives you 50 rep to start with!

You ***don't*** *need* any reputation on any other SE site. Although it is recommended to at least have experience on the SE platform, so you have more of an idea of how SE sites work, etc...

Please search on Area51 before you create a proposal so you don't make a dupe! (As you would do on any other normal SE site!)

As @ShadowWizard says, *at least* 100 users who *commit* must have *at least* 200 rep *on another site* in order to get to the *private beta* stage.

Comment: Maybe worth to mention here that SE reputation is important to bring a proposal to the final stage of private beta: in the commitment phase, at least 100 of the users who commit must have 200 rep on at least one site: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ECKSs.png